# Polybar default content

Tags: temperature, info

I've installed `polybar` and `bspwm`, I don't know what `25°C` refer to, and `56%` [image: show here]

absolutely it's not my CPU temperature

Comment: You do not understand a temp of 25 degrees Celsius?

Comment: Temperature of what 
Is that my GPU temperature or HDD or CPU or what?

Comment: Sounds like a question you need to ask the people that made that software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/: 56%` in the screenshot refers to the [filesystem module](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/wiki/Module:-filesystem).

In the config that you are using, that module shows you how much disk space you used in your root partition (mountpoint `/`).

---

The `25°C` comes from the [temperature module](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/wiki/Module:-temperature).

In your case, this probably just displays what's in `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`. You can figure out what kind of temperature that is by reading what's in the file at `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/type`.
On all systems that I have tried, this was `x86_pkg_temp` and did represent the CPU temperature, though 25 degrees Celsius is kind of low.